# What endpoint do I hit for this Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, http, url, rest

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

"user_online_presence"

What endpoint do I hit? I want to know what users are online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just redirect user to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=user_online_presence
```

In documentation: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Yes, I have the access_token. Now, I want to use it. I want to check if the user is online. What endpoint do I hit for that?

Comment: How can I do it with the Graph API endpoint? https://graph.facebook.com/me/ FQL is silly :/

Comment: You can with this URI: https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY 
Read the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/